# Trying to encrypt string to ASCII

Tags: python, encryption

This is what I have not sure where I am going wrong:

```
import sys
message = input("enter message here:")
Key = input("enter a key from 1-100:")

for Letter in message:
        Char = ord(Letter)
        if (Char + Key) < 32:
            encryptedChar = ((Char - Key) + 127) - 32
        else:
            encryptedChar = (Char - Key)
            sys.stdout.write(chr(encryptedChar))

            print(encryptedChar,end=" ")
```

I'm currently receiving the error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str')
```

Comment: Are you trying to implement a [caesar cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher)?

Comment: Assuming you're in python3, the problem is that you're trying to do `Char` which is an integer `+ Key` which is a string.

Comment: (TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str') this is the error I get.

Comment: For a Caesar cipher you have to iterate through the characters in the key. Please edit clarifications into your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
Key = int(input("enter a key from 1-100:"))
```

`input` is a string, you need to cast as an integer.

After casting to an int your code runs fine:

```
enter message here:foobar
enter a key from 1-100:10
\92e101e101X88W87h104
```